# Why i get err in codewars but i don't have err in vsCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, error-handling

***Why i get this error?When i compleate this code is vsCode it have no problems but i get error in codeWars complete.It's a calculations using functions.
ex:
This time we want to write calculations using functions and get the results. Let's have a look at some examples:

Requirements:

There must be a function for each number from 0 ("zero") to 9 ("nine")
There must be a function for each of the following mathematical operations: plus, minus, times, dividedBy (divided_by in Ruby and Python)
Each calculation consist of exactly one operation and two numbers
The most outer function represents the left operand, the most inner function represents the right operand

---

```
function zero(firstArg = 0,myValue = 0){
        return firstArg.times === `*`?myValue * firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `/`?myValue / firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `+`?myValue + firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `-`?myValue - firstArg.value : myValue
    }
    function one(firstArg = 0,myValue = 1){
        return firstArg.times === `*`?myValue * firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `/`?myValue / firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `+`?myValue + firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `-`?myValue - firstArg.value : myValue
    }
    function two(firstArg = 0,myValue = 2){
        return firstArg.times === `*`?myValue * firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `/`?myValue / firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `+`?myValue + firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `-`?myValue - firstArg.value : myValue
    }
    function three(firstArg = 0,myValue = 3){
        return firstArg.times === `*`?myValue * firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `/`?myValue / firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `+`?myValue + firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `-`?myValue - firstArg.value : myValue
    }
    function four(firstArg = 0,myValue = 4){
        return firstArg.times === `*`?myValue * firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `/`?myValue / firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `+`?myValue + firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `-`?myValue - firstArg.value : myValue
    }
    function five(firstArg = 0,myValue = 5){
        return firstArg.times === `*`?myValue * firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `/`?myValue / firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `+`?myValue + firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `-`?myValue - firstArg.value : myValue
    }
    function six(firstArg = 0,myValue = 6){
        return firstArg.times === `*`?myValue * firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `/`?myValue / firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `+`?myValue + firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `-`?myValue - firstArg.value : myValue
    }
    function seven(firstArg = 0,myValue = 7){
        return firstArg.times === `*`?myValue * firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `/`?myValue / firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `+`?myValue + firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `-`?myValue - firstArg.value : myValue
    }
    function eight(firstArg = 0,myValue = 8){
        return firstArg.times === `*`?myValue * firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `/`?myValue / firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `+`?myValue + firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `-`?myValue - firstArg.value : myValue
    }
    function nine(firstArg = 0,myValue = 9){
        return firstArg.times === `*`?myValue * firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `/`?myValue / firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `+`?myValue + firstArg.value :
        firstArg.times === `-`?myValue - firstArg.value : myValue
    }

    function plus(value){
        return {value,times:'+'}
    }
    function minus(value){
        return {value,times:'-'}
    }
    function times(value){
        return {value,times:'*'}
    }
    function dividedBy(value){
        return {value,times:'/'}
    }

    console.log(five(times(two())))
```

error:

```
/home/codewarrior/index.js:91
}
^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at [eval]:1:1
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What error are you getting? You need to include both the code and the actual error (or invalid output if there is no actual error).

Comment: /home/codewarrior/index.js:91
}
^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list